# Can mongo has $cond in $push?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to push 1 item to array and save it to mongo if that item is not existed in array.

Sample: I have a record with an array

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('xxxxx'),
  userEmails: [
    {
      email: 'xxx@gmail.com,
      addedAt: ISODate('xxx')
    }
  ]
}
```

Current query:

```
db.users.updateOne(
  { _id: ObjectId('xxxxx') },
  {
    $push: {
      userEmails: {
        email: 'xxx@gmail.com',
        addedAt: new Date(),
      }
    }
  }
);
```

I expect if `xxx@gmail.com` is existed, it shouldn't pushed to array. I don't want array have duplicated items

Comment: Would [$addToSet](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) work?

Comment: @user20042973 seems good with array's item is string or number. In my case, it's a nested array, item is an object, so I need a query to filter like this { email: { $ne: 'xxx.gmail.com' } }

Comment: I tried, if object have same attribute name with same value, it's worked. But actually, my object have another attribute as added time. I updated my question, because addedTime is not same value, so $addToSet is didn't work @user20042973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here We are specifying condition that if xxx@gmail.com is not inside userEmail then only we are pushing data.

```
db.users.updateOne(
{ _id: ObjectId('xxxxx'),"userEmails.email":{$ne: "xxx@gmail.com"} },
{
  $push: {
    userEmails: {
      email: 'xxx@gmail.com',
      addedAt: new Date(),
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks, very simple and I didn't think about it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a condition in $push, the best way to go will be to go with the $nin operation.

**({name: {$nin: ["Shehroz", "virk"]}})**

You can replace name with the user Email, so that it verifies the condition before updating

Comment: Can you provide full query

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).